# PDF from SFMC Cloud Page?

Tags: marketing-cloud, pdf, cloudpagesurl, webstudio

I am looking for a way to use Cloud Pages to build a PDF. Use case: User gets email with a link "click here for account summary" and the info needed to build the account summary is in a DE.  Then, the link is to a Cloud page that can retrieve data from that DE to build a PDF.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Marketing Cloud does not have native PDF creation functionality. You would have to pull the data in the DE and send to a 3rd party who provide the PDF generation service with these information and get the PDF link.

In case it's a fixed PDF file, then you can upload the PDF directly in content builder and put the link in the email something like this:

```HTML
Download PDF <a href="https://Your PDF file URL in Content Builder.pdf" download>HERE
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

No reason why you can't generate a PDF using client-side JavaScript on a CloudPage.

Steps would be:

1. send an email that targets the CloudPage
2. use AMPscript or SSJS to retrieve the send context and generate an HTML document before the page loads
3. pass the generated HTML into the client-side JS library
4. execute the PDF build process

Here are several options: [A full comparison of 6 JS libraries for generating PDFs](https://dev.to/handdot/generate-a-pdf-in-js-summary-and-comparison-of-libraries-3k0p)